# Can't run Python Script on remote VM via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, cmd, windows-10, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM into which I SSH in. The VM is a W10 host.
I can create files with touch, change directories and so on, but whenever I try to run a python script that is hosted on the VM I get the following error:

> The system cannot execute the specified program.

At first glance I thought that there was a problem related to my pyhton alias and the PATH variable, so I decided to use RDP to log into the machine, open a CMD and try the same command, which worked just fine. The python program executed flawlessly.

I used `where` to find where is my python.exe located at, so whenever I run the script on my remote terminal I can do something like:

```
C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe test.py
```

This does result in the same error message as the one stated above.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Is is OpenSSH? which service account that its running on?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana I installed OpenSSH, following this tutorial: https://adamtheautomator.com/openssh-windows/#Downloading_OpenSSH
As per 'Service Account' I'm not sure I've understood your question, are you asking under which user I've installed OpenSSH? If not, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Have you gave the permissions as this tutorial. How to Start the OpenSSH Server in Windows 10 
https://winaero.com/enable-openssh-server-windows-10/

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana I've tried following the tutorial but I can't get it to work, I'm stuck on step 7. https://gyazo.com/d914f006bdd0bb5a419187097ee72e0a

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana as per this tutotial, since i'm using password authentication, I don't need to further configure OpenSSH. Please do correct me If I'm mistaken. Once again the same OpenSSHUtils line appears, at this point I'm not even sure I need to use it since Im not suing private keys to access

Comment: You need to give related file permission's for sshd service have you add NT Service\sshd user to relevant group? please refer title "How to Start the OpenSSH Server in Windows 10" in this url https://winaero.com/enable-openssh-server-windows-10/

Comment: IS the user you use for RDP the same as the one you use for SSH? Can you run any python program (like a simple print hello world) at all whilst on SSH? Does you program require any input or libraries with GUI elements?

Comment: @JustLudo Yes the RDP credentials are the same as the SSH ones, I can't even run a hello world on ssh.
My program doesn't make use of GUI, the only library being used is an API called SonarQubeClient

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana The tutorial you keep referring me to needs an update I'm afraid. The service when installing is no longer named sshd, but openssh shh server. Also, when tabing to the Log On window the option checked is Local System Account. It  must have been changed over time

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to execute your command as below.

```
ssh user@machine python < script.py
```